# Vba Ms-Word Nested Error Control

Tags: vba, error-handling, ms-word

I'm trying this time to handle errors between nested subs. For example:

```
Sub A()
    On Error GoTo errormsg

    Call B
    Call C
    Exit Sub
errormsg:
    MsgBox "Error in A", vbOKOnly, "Warning"
End Sub

Sub B()
    On Error GoTo errormsg

    Call D
    Exit Sub
errormsg:
    MsgBox "Error in B",vbOKOnly,"Warning"
End Sub

Sub C()
    On Error Goto errormsg

    '...

    Exit Sub
errormsg:
    MsgBox "Error in C",vbOKOnly,"Warning"
End Sub

Sub D()
    On Error GoTo errormsg  
    '...
    Err.Raise 6 'overflow error
    '...
    Exit Sub
errormsg:
    MsgBox "Error in D",vbOKOnly,"Warning"
End Sub
```

Well, If there is an error when calling D from B(from A), ErrorD shows, but not ErrorB neither ErrorA. What am I doing/understanding wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Your error handlers are running whether or not there's an error. Can you try to make the code a little bit more realistic, just to make a clear question? Pro-tip: the more effort you put in your question, the more likely you are to get an answer with as much effort.

Comment: Well, sorry, inside all "DO STUFF" you may suppose there is a "EXIT SUB". Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Why that overflow error?

P.D.: My first comment :)))))

Comment: @RubénPS I put it in just to illustrate OP's intention of blowing things up in `Sub D`. Sorry if it muds things up, feel free to take it out.

Comment: Not my post, I only wanted to know why is it there ^-^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`On Error GoTo [error-handler-label]` tells VBA to jump to the specified label whenever a runtime error occurs in a method. When you use error handlers, you're telling VBA "it's all good, no need to blow everything up, I can handle it". So when `Sub D` runs:

> ```
> Sub D()
>     On Error GoTo errormsg  
>     '...
>     Err.Raise 6 'overflow error
>     '...
>     Exit Sub
> errormsg:
>     MsgBox "Error in D",vbOKOnly,"Warning"
> End Sub
> ```

When execution reaches the line that throws an error, VBA jumps to the `errormsg` label and you should see the "Error in D" message. Then execution returns to the caller (`Sub B`) and, as far as the runtime is concerned, the error that was raised in D was taken care of (because you told it "I'll handle it" with that `On Error` statement), so execution resumes with the `Exit Sub` statement and returns to `Sub A` to run `Sub C`.

If you want runtime errors to "bubble up", you either need to re-raise them in the error handling subroutine:

```
Err.Raise Err.Number 'per Err.Raise specs, current Err values are reused when only the Number parameter is specified
```

...Or you remove the handler in `Sub D` and decide to handle it higher up in the call stack. For example, if you remove all handlers *except* in `Sub A`, then you will see "Error in A" with the error message actually being that of the error that was raised in `Sub D` - unfortunately without any way of telling where in the call stack that error occurred, because VBA doesn't expose its call stack.

Re-raising the error in every error handler should pop the follow messages, in that order:

- Error in D
- Error in B
- Error in A
- [and if you re-raise in A then VBA blows up here if A was your starting point]

Comment: So...the thing I need to do is this??
  `Sub D()  On error goto errormsg.....Errormsg: Msgbox "blablabla" 
Err.Raise Err.Number
end sub`

Comment: @Mat's Mug But if you do that, won't it give you back the same error without handling before leaving D?

Comment: @RubénPS depends how important it is to know that the error originated in D, but yes, that's why I mention removing the handlers and catch everything in A.